# PHP update quantity in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index] => 0
            [quantity] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_product] => 20
                    [title] => Oranges
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_product] => 24
                    [title] => Bananas
                )

        )

)
```

To make this array, this is my code:

```
$i = 0;
$content = array();
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $result){

        foreach($result as $item){

            $values = $product->getById($item['id']);

            if($values != null){ // which means it has product

                /*
                    Checks if the array already contains that ID
                    this avoids duplicated products
                */
                if(main::search_multidimensional($content, "id_product", $item['id_product']) == null){
                    $content[] = array("index" => $i, "quantity" => 1, $values);
                    $i++;
                }else{ /* 
                            in case it does have already the id_product in the array
                            I should update the "quantity" according to the "index".
                        */

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $content;
```

My problem is after the `}else{`. I've been trying some codes without any success. I have to update the quantity according to the index. Although if you guys think there's a better alternative please let me know.

**Edit**: Since most of the people is worried about the search_multidimensional and it might be my solution, here's the function:

```
public function search_multidimensional($array, $key, $value){
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $array;
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, self::search_multidimensional($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: What `main::search_multidimensional()` do? Where is its code?

Comment: If `main::search_multidimensional` doesn't return the correct array, it's not going to update the values.  Do `print_r(main::search_multidimensional` to see if it's returning the correct array, then update accordingly.

Comment: Well, I think it's not relevant for the problem, but, as the name says, it searchs for a Key and a Value in a specific array.

Comment: @Axel the `main::search_multidimensional` only checks if exists or not the Key and Value in the specific array, nothing else.

Comment: Your `main::search_multidimensional` should return index of found element in the array. In this case your problem become trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**. 
All I had to do was to forget the `$i` variable, since it wasn't actually doing something **necessary**. Since I have `id_product`, which is unique I need to work with it.

```
if($values != null){ // Only if it has results

    // checks if array already contains or not the product ID

    // if does not have, it will add
    if(global_::search_multidimensional($content, "id_product", $item['id_product']) == null){
        $content[] = array("index" => $item['id_product'], "quantity" => 1, $values);
        // index is now the id of the product
    }else{

        // otherwise, loop all the elements and add +1
        foreach($content as $key => $result){
            if($item['id_product'] == $content[$key]['index']){ 
                $content[$key]['quantity']++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**

In that case, would this help? (Since your search_multidimensional only returns a true or false)

```
$i = 0;
$content = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $result){
        foreach($result as $item){
            $values = $product->getById($item['id']);

            if($values != null) { // which means it has product
                /*
                    Checks if the array already contains that ID
                    this avoids duplicated products
                */
                $product_exists = false;
                foreach($content as &$cItem) {
                    if($cItem['values']['id_product'] == $item['id_product']) {
                        $cItem['values']['quantity']++; // Increments the quantity by 1

                        $product_exists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If the product does not exist in $content, add it in.
                if(!$product_exists)
                    $content[] = array("index" => $i, "quantity" => 1, "values" => $values);

                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Edited again to give an array key to $values)

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

<strike>Since you are recreating the cart array in `$content`, you could just do this in your else:</strike>

`$content[] = array("index" => $i, "quantity" => $result['quantity'] + 1, $values);`

Such that it would show like this:

```
$i = 0;
$content = array();

if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $result){
        foreach($result as $item){
            $values = $product->getById($item['id']);

            if($values != null){ // which means it has product
                /*
                    Checks if the array already contains that ID
                    this avoids duplicated products
                */
                if(main::search_multidimensional($content, "id_product", $item['id_product']) == null)
                    $content[] = array("index" => $i, "quantity" => 1, $values); 
                else
                    $content[] = array("index" => $i, "quantity" => $result['quantity'] + 1, $values); // Retrieve current quantity and adds 1

                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm assuming you are only increasing the quantity by 1)

Comment: Thanks, but actually no. `$_SESSION['cart']` does not contain the quantity and it contains duplicateds. What I'm doing now is the checkout, so I have to remove all the duplicateds and implement +1 (in quantity) whenever already exists that `id_product` in the array `$content`.
With your code I'll have always duplicateds because it actually adds after the `}else{` and not updates (which is what I want).

Comment: @user3355243 I've edited the answer from better understanding what you meant.

Comment: Not really, actually I have several errors (which are normal, because, for example, `$content[0]['id_product']` does not exists.. I think one of the problems is that I might have not explained myself very well.

Comment: @user3355243 I've edited it to give $values an array key, should fix the does not exist issue. Give it a try

Comment: it continues to give error `Notice:  Undefined index: id_product` and it's normal. `if($cItem['values']['id_product'] == $item['id_product']) { ` you are telling that the variable $content has already "values" (which I dont know where did you get that) and "id_product" which, if you look at my array, doesn't have also.

Comment: Then we might need to look at what `$values = $product->getById($item['id']);` does.

Answer (score 0):

As your `$content` array has fixed structure (fixed number of levels) you don't need to use recursive function. Your `search_multidimensional` function could be much simpler. And it should return index of found element (if any) in the array:

```
function search_multidimensional($array, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($array as $i => $el) {
        foreach ($el as $j => $v) {
            if (is_int($j) && isset($v[$key]) && $v[$key] == $value) return $i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So the snippet building `$content` should be changed like this:

```
...
if (($index = search_multidimensional($content, "id_product", $item['id_product'])) === false) {
    $content[] = array("index" => $i, "quantity" => 1, $values); $i++;
}
else {
    $content[$index]['quantity']++;
}
```

Comment: I have solved the issue but I have gave your code a try and I get two errors. `Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in $content[$index]['quantity']++;` and also `Notice:  Undefined index: quantity` in the same line. The problem might be the `search_multidimensional`.